# Storing values from checkboxes in database

Tags: python, beginner, django

I'm getting values from 2 checkboxes and save those values to a database.

I don't like these `if` statements. How is it possible to simplify the code?

```
def edit_user(request, user_id):

user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

if request.POST:

    if request.POST.get('is_staff'):
        user.is_staff = True
    else:
        user.is_staff = False

    if request.POST.get('is_active'):
        user.is_active = True
    else:
        user.is_active = False

    user.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
```

Comment: Your indentation seems to be off. This looks like a simple copy & paste error. Try pasting your code, selecting it all, and pressing either CTRL-K or the `{}` button in the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the default parameter from the get method.
[Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.get)

```
if request.POST:
        user.is_staff = request.POST.get('is_staff', False)
        user.is_active = request.POST.get('is_active', False)
        user.save()
```

Answer (score -1):

Since your code implies that request.POST.get('is_staff')` returns a boolean (because you are using it in an if statement), you can just assign the variable directly rather than using the if. The following shows this implimented.

```
user.is_staff = request.POST.get('is_staff')

user.is_active = request.POST.get('is_active')
```

Comment: Can you help the OP improve their ability to code, rather than just dump some code? Also, are you sure they are the same?

Comment: since op is using `request.POST.get('is_staff')` in an if statement, it presumably returns a boolean value, so assigning the variable directly to it, should be the same as using an if statement and assigning to true/false

Comment: So you're assuming `POST.get` can't return `None` or `'hello'`. That's poor. And no "returns a boolean (because you are using it in an if statement)" is just wrong with Python.

Comment: the other thing is that even if it doesn´t return a boolean, we know that the value it returns is either truthy or falsy, depending on which we reach, so it probably will still work.

Comment: If you're going to make assumptions, then please describe the assumption, and explain how the assumption affects the code. Yes it's likely to work the same way, but no `POST.get('is_staff')` is not guaranteed to be a boolean, and may be problematic if the OP uses it a certain way. Putting typed data into a database with `user.save()` is one such place I'd expect to error if you assign a string to it.

Answer (score -2):

My updated code looks like that:

```
def edit_user(request, user_id):

    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)

    if request.POST:

        user.is_staff = True if request.POST.get('is_staff') else False
        user.is_active = True if request.POST.get('is_active') else False
        user.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', '/'))
```

Comment: While [users are encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) to [answer their own question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), "_Answers that merely provide an alternate solution with no explanation or justification do not constitute valid Code Review answers_" - from [How do I write a good answer?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Just so you know you can use `bool` rather than a ternary.